# why java script executor can not click all objects using selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I can click all objects by javascript executor but some of the objects I could not click via javascript executor and those objects can be clicked by `click()`, 
for example:

```
 driver.findelement(locator).click();
```

Please clarify the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use "Javascript", not "java script" as it can be misleading.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Also, `selenium-webdriver`: "When using this tag, also add a tag for the programming language you are using." - I doubt thats javascript.

Comment: Thanks,  Some of the elements i can click by driver.findelements(By.id("xyz")).click and something i could not so i choose javascript executor. Query is i want to use any one either javascript executor or driver.findelement(locator).click. pls guide me..